# Subtract minutes From time using angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Currently I am working with ionic 3 with angular 4 project,In which I need to subtract 10 minutes from Time, which is picked from time picker in HH:MM format.

example :

```
   I have variable `X = 06:30` ; Now i have to subtract `10` minutes from `X`.
```

How it will get deal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install moment [**guide**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/)

```
npm i moment --save
```

Import it

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Use this this line of code

```
const res = moment("06:30","hh:mm").subtract(10, 'minutes');
```

Have a look at the **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/rzm4hfb0/205/)** I created

Comment: Thanks @Microsmsm ,this is exactly I wanted. thanks a lot .